# Katalon Studio An internal error occurred during: "Scanning for step definitions". Index: 5, Size: 5

Tags: groovy, cucumber, katalon-studio

I'm having problems when trying to recalculate steps and find steps on my Cucumber code in Katalon Studio. It throws error "An internal error occurred during: "Scanning for step definitions".
Index: 5, Size: 5" .

I was create a feature for register account on Katalon Studio. Here's the Register.Feature code:

```
Feature: Register User
  Register User

  Background:
  Given User is on register page
  
  Scenario Outline: Register User Normally
    Given User want to register account
    When User typing on register form
    Then Display success message

    Examples: 
     | firstname | lastname | email | password | confirmpassword | gender  |
     | Septian | Adi | septian.andika@mail.com | User123! | male |
```

And here's the Groovy Scripts for Register Feature:

```
class register {
    @Given("User is on register page")
    def open_website() {
        WebUI.openBrowser(null)
        WebUI.setViewPortSize(1600, 900)
        WebUI.navigateToUrl(GlobalVariable.url)
        println("Opened Fast Social Website")
    }

    @Given("User want to register account")
    def open_register_page() {
        WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/daftarBtn'))
        WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/Global/header'), 1)
        WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/Global/subHeader'), 1)
        WebUI.verifyElementText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Global/header'), "Daftar")
        WebUI.verifyElementText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Global/subHeader'), "Buat Akun Fast Social Anda!")
        println("Opened Register Page")
    }

    @When("User typing on register form")
    def type_register_form(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password, String gender) {
        WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/firstNameForm'), firstname)
        println("Inputted : " +firstname)
        WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/lastnNameForm'), lastname)
        println("Inputted : " +lastname)
        WebUI.setText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/emailForm'), email)
        println("Inputted : " +email)
        WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Login Page/passwordForm'), password)
        println("Inputted : " +password)
        WebUI.setEncryptedText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/confrimPasswordForm'), password)
        println("Inputted : " +password)
        WebUI.selectOptionByIndex(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/genderForm'), 1)
        println("Selected : " +gender)
        WebUI.check(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/acceptTermsCheck'))
        WebUI.verifyElementChecked(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/acceptTermsCheck'), 1)
        println("Accepted Terms")
        WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/registerButton'))
        println("Clicked Register Button")
    }

    @Then("Display Success Message")
    def verify_message() {
        WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/alertSuccess'), 1)
        WebUI.verifyElementText(findTestObject('Object Repository/Register Page/alertSuccess'), "Registrasi berhasil! Kami telah mengirimkan email kepada Anda, Silakan periksa kotak masuk/spam Anda untuk memverifikasi email Anda.")
        WebUI.takeScreenshot('Screenshots/successRegister.png')
    }
}
```

When I try to Recalculate Steps and Find Steps, the Katalon Studio throw error:
[Katalon Studio error scanning for steps definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECtFL.png)

I'm using Katalon Studio 8.6.0 on Windows 11 Pro, I was upgraded my Katalon Studio to 8.6.5 but still no luck.